# LDAP Authentication in C# - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, authentication, ldap

I'm trying to authenticate users through LDAP in C#. Each time I try to log in, I get the 'Input string was not in a correct format' error.

This is my connection string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://123.193.111.22:389.local" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider"><providers>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
    connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
    type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
    System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    connectionUsername="MyUsername"
    connectionPassword="MyPassword" 
    connectionProtection="Secure"
    enableSearchMethods="true" />
    </providers>
    </membership>
    <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Admin/Login" 
    timeout="450" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/>
</authentication>
```

The error seems to be at ***type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider***. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have an `<authentication/>` element wrapped in an `<authentication/>` element?

Comment: Oh sorry, must have fudged it up when I was copy pasting the code. It's not there in the source code.

Comment: Are you sure that you can use a ldap url like thatLDAP://123.193.111.22:389.local? Did you try LDAP://123.193.111.22.local:389 already?

Comment: I did try that, keep getting an 'Unable to establish secure connection with the server' error.

Comment: But this looks like another problem ... http://forums.asp.net/t/1166503.aspx/1

Comment: Yeah, read that thread before. Maybe I'll ask my system admin to assign me a privileged account. Just wanted to check in case it's a code issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out. Had to rework the membership provider code and now I'm able to authenticate users.